Buildfire: login api
I am trying to use the BuildFire SSO API to integrate our user logins with our app. We are using .Net Core 7 and Web API for endpoints. I am filling out the custom SSO fields on the login setup screen (login api, register url, access token validator, etc). The page itself did not have much specifics for what is expected of the endpoints but I did find this write up: https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/using-single-sign-on-sso which I used. Though I do notice the settings screen wants you to choose a structured form type for the post body yet the doc shows an example of the model in JSON. I tried binding both ways during testing just in case [FromBody] and [FromForm] and neither seemed to make a difference.
When attempting to use the test login function from the control panel I keep getting the following:
Starting Testing , Please login on the emulator side...
Error status:500
Error details:"{"errorMessage":"ISE"}"
The other entries for register and forgot password work fine it is just the login that I get an error on. Also, haven't been able to find any docs on what the message ISE stands for.
Created the endpoints and tried with and without a model to bind to. Tried binding as if the payload was from the form or as JSON and didn't make a difference. Endpoint is accessible when posting directly to it but not from BuildFire's control panel.

500 usually means an error processing your request and not a rejected request. I'd follow up with their support.

As it turns out for anyone who might have the same issue. The connection was coming from a remote server and not directly from the BuildFire dev emulator running in my browser hence it could not connect to my local test web server like the other endpoints could. Moved to a public facing web server and the login endpoint works.
